# I want a function to make a calculation in another function C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I try to make a function in C++ to assign a value to a variable and keep it, But I want to make with **void function**.
This is the Main function;

```
int main(){
    //declar variables
    double sales=0.0,commission=0.0,totalCom=0.0,totalSales=0.0,totalEmployee=0.0;
    //call soldEmployee function
    sales = soldEmployee(sales);    
    // if use enter sales negative the programe end
    while(sales > 0){
        //call calc commission
        commisionCalc(sales,commission);
        //call display commission
        displayCom(commission);
        //call display total (commission + sale)
        disTotal(sales,commission,totalEmployee);
        // ask user to put input again
        sales = soldEmployee(sales);
    }
    total(totalSales,commission);

    return 0;
 } //end of main function
```

And this the function;

```
double soldEmployee(double &s){//function to get the user input
    cout << "Next Sales: "; cin >> s;   
    return s;   
}

void commisionCalc(double s, double &com){//function to calc commission
    com = s * 0.10;
}

void displayCom(double c){;// function to display commission
    cout <<fixed << setprecision(2) << "Commision= " << c << endl;
}

void disTotal(double s,double com,double &total){// function to get commission + sales
    total = s + com;
    cout << "Salary + Com: " << total << endl;
}

void total(double t, double &total){// function to get the total of all employee commision and store it in total sales
    t += total;
    cout << "Total Salary: " << total << endl;
}
```

So, in function **total** I want to make it assign the commission I get into the totalSales, I know that the name of variables seems confusing but, this is because I made some modifies in the program.
Can anyone help me explain how to make because I stuck when I made many function.
and if you asking that there is a easy way to make i want this way because it's a assignment not work to learn how to make function and get used to it.

Comment: So what is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: Are you expecting `t += total;` to modify `total`?

Comment: yeah exactly I wanna assign what will get in total in t that will be in the main function **totalSales**, then display it.

Comment: that the totalSales in the main function not display the total commission or the total sales it display the commission it self not all the commission that i got

Comment: how about `total += t`?

Comment: not working, it display only the last commission that appears, like it makes copy from it, not get the sum of it EDIT: In the assignment they wanna me to make a function not only make total += t.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're doing in `main`.You should implement it with functions that return values, and once that's working, try to implement it with void functions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood the your problem, but if what you need is to have the variable `totalSales` in the main changed inside the `total` function so that its modified value would be accessible from the main, you should do the following:

```cpp
// note below the "double &t" which is now passed by reference.
void total(double &t, double total){
    t += total;
    cout << "Total Salary: " << total << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but still not working so, I made a function to display total, and then assigned what i get in commission then pass as an argument in total(totalCommission), and it's works